# RCT power for optimal design

Tags: experimental-economics, randomized-experiment

I have a question regarding Optimal Design software.

Particularly, let's suppose I have an intervention that assigns police patrols to different street segments, and that these segments are randomized so that half receive the treatment and the other half doesn't. If I am doing this, should I use person randomized trials, or the would the correct decision be to use clustered randomized trials with clustered-level outcomes?

Comment: Is this really a software question?

Comment: Sounds like a cluster-level intervention to me. But another question: Shouldn't we expect contamination if treatment and control are on the same street? Especially if we talk about crime outcomes.

Comment: Yes, there could be some contamination, but generally the literature determines a minimum distance of 200m-250m between street segments to prevent that issue. Thank you for solving my question!